# Expo + Firebase authentication (Identity Toolkit) API key android restriction

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, expo

In short: Can android app, done with Expo, using Firebase authentication (Identity Toolkit) API key be restricted to use android app? Email/Password authentication

I have an android application that uses Firebase's services. I have added android application in my Firebase project and tried to restrict the android application auto generated key (in Google console) but have not been successful.

-I have used https://docs.expo.io/guides/using-firebase/ for **Firebase SDK setup**.

-Downloaded google-service.json, added it to root of project (same level that app.json is in) and defined it in app.json "expo.android.googleServicesFile": "./google-services.json".

-And at the Google console to the autogenerated api key for my Firebase project's android app:
--I have defined **"Android apps" application restrictions**,
--added Package name from app.json **"expo.android.package"**
--and gotten the SHA-1 certificate fingerprint from [https://expo.dev/accounts/{username}/projects/{project}/credentials](https://expo.dev/accounts/%7Busername%7D/projects/%7Bproject%7D/credentials)
**Classic Android Credentials: Build Credentials: SHA-1 Certificate Fingerprint**.

I have been able to restrict Maps SDK for Android and Geocoding API with this same way stated up.

I have not yet added the application to Google Play.

I have not found solution through testing and googling if there is instructions for this kind of situation.
**Thank you for all the help!**

EDIT:
I also looked my build logs: Reading manifest.
-I don't know if oauth_client is needed for this but values under it are same as given in Firebase project and **client.oauth_client.client_id** is same as autogenerated OAuth 2.0 Client IDs key in Google credentials
-**client.api_key** is same as in Google credentials page

**EDIT2**
-Now I recreated android project in Firebase and it connected to existing api key on GCP (the one I use for Maps and Geocoding with working restriction). So I changed the key used in my android project to correspond the api key and now **I get a new error message when trying to login**:

```
FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/requests-from-this-android-client-application-<empty>-are-blocked.).
```

Comment: Any one got any ideas or similar use cases? Haven't found solution. I don't know if adding application to Google Play and thus getting new SHA keys would work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem solved by itself. Importing "./google-services.json" and restricting applications API key with package name (and in Android SHA-1 certificate fingerprint) has now worked.

In the end I don't know what caused the problem prior, but now the Expo application both in Android and iOS is restricted and working as expected.